# statistical analysis of double-treated sample data from poisson distribution

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, poisson-distribution, wilcoxon-signed-rank, paired-comparisons

I have a question regarding the statistical significance in a biological experiment I conducted.

There are cells (n=51), which are treated with chemical P (n=27) or untreated (¬P, n=24). I measure a rate of events happening inside the cells which seems to follow a Poisson distribution (mean around 1 events/s).

Directly after measuring this “baseline” rate (with 10 time points per cell), I add either chemical N or chemical C to the respective cell and keep measuring (i.e. I have a paired measurement before and after treatment on the same cell). In total I have measured 13 cells with ¬P and added N, 11 cells with ¬P and added C, 13 cells with P and added N, and 14 cells with P and added C. After treatment I have 60 time points per cell.

My first hypothesis is that P treated cells have a reduced rate with respect to untreated (¬P) cells. This should be independent of N or C, i.e. also after treatment with C, the P group gives me smaller rates. The same goes for treatment with N.

My second hypothesis is that N increases the rate compared to the baseline.
Regarding the effect of C, I would like to test the hypothesis that C has no effect.

Glen_b suggested in a previous version of the question that it might be possible to use a Poisson GLM (given that it is set up correctly) or a GLMM, but I have a hard time setting it up correctly (or at all). Could someone help me with this or suggest alternative means of analysis?

Comment: 1. How do you get 3-way anova out of two treatments? What was the third IV?  2. What's the hypothesis or hypotheses you are interested in?

Comment: The existence of paired measurement is so fundamental to the analysis that I am astounded you only mention it now. I am not sure of the structure of the design now, so it would need to be made crystal clear in the question. *None* of the analyses you considered are suitable for paired responses; a Poisson GLM might be used but it has to be set up the right way (and may not be what you want, since pairs would be set up as fixed efffects); a GLMM would probably be more suitable, though once I understand the actual experiment, that might be best done another way.

Comment: My present answer is of little use in the face of that missing information.  I am unsure whether to suggest you post an entirely new question or whether to delete my answer and leave you to edit this question into a radically different question. Since nobody has seen enough value in my answer so far to offer any upvotes perhaps I should delete it.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you believe your response is conditionally Poisson, the obvious model would be a Poisson GLM. ANOVA is unsuitable for count data for a number of reasons; e.g.

   (i) counts will have variance related to mean (i.e. will be heteroskedastic), and
   (ii) small counts are distinctly non-normal
2. You should not do one way ANOVA (or any similar analysis, including Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney or Poisson regression on only one IV) when you know there's more than one treatment that has been applied.
3. Whether you do a main-effects model or a model with interaction in your Poisson GLM is up to you; that would relate to your subject-area knowledge and needs. (If you don't know which you want, I'd suggest including interaction.)

It's difficult to say more in the absence of any discussion of what hypotheses you want to test.

Comment: Thanks for your comments so far. 

The first measurement on the P and ¬P cells is to establish a baseline for both cases, treated and untreated. The hypothesis is that the treated case will give me a lower rate. 

The chemicals N and C should, by my hypothesis, have effects independent of P, where N should increase the rate, while C (a control chemical) should be without effect.

Comment: Also, I measured the change in rate upon treatment with N or C cell-wise, so I have paired measurements.

Comment: The paired measurement is so fundamental to the analysis that I am astounded you only mention it now. *None* of the analyses you considered are suitable for paired responses; a Poisson GLM might be used but it has to be set up the right way (and may not be what you seek); a GLMM may be more suitable.

Comment: Thank you Glen_b!

What software would you suggest for the analysis then?

Comment: We haven't got as far as a suitable analysis yet. The paired thing needs to be clearly explained in the text of the question. Could you edit all the information from comments into your question (and expand on the design of the experiment plus more clearly indicate the hypothesis of interest)? I will still likely delete my answer (since it won't answer the edited question), but if I can edit to make it relevant I will do so and undelete. If it was me doing it I'd probably work in R but many packages should be able to do something suitable -- once we are clearer about what you need.

Comment: I have rephrased the question now.